# Pandas DataFrame removing NaN rows based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Pandas DataFrame removing NaN rows based on condition.

I'm trying to remove the rows whose `gender==male` and `status == NaN`.

Sample df:

```
        name     status        gender   leaves
0       tom        NaN          male      5 
1       tom        True         male      6
2       tom        True         male      7
3       mary       True         female    1
4       mary       NaN          female    10
5       mary       True         female    15
6       john       NaN          male       2
7       mark      True          male       3
```

Expected Ouput:

```
        name     status        gender   leaves
0       tom        True         male      6
1       tom        True         male      7
2       mary       True         female    1
3       mary       NaN          female    10
4       mary       True         female    15
5       mark      True          male       3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html) (or `isnull`) function to get the rows with a value of `NaN`.
With this knowledge, you can filter your dataframe using something like:

```py
conditions = (df.gender == 'male')&(df.status.isna())
filtered_df = df[~conditions]
```

Answer (score 0):

Good One given by @Derlin, other way I tried is using `fillna()` filled `NaN` with -1 and indexed them, just like below:

```py
>>> df[~((df.fillna(-1)['status']==-1)&(df['gender']=='male'))]
```

Just for reference `~` operator is the same as `np.logical_not()` of `numpy`. So if you use this:
`df[np.logical_not((df.fillna(-1)['status']==-1)&(df['gender']=='male'))]` (dont forget to `import numpy as np`), means the same.